# What metrics can be used to measure the difference in connectivity between graphs?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, multiple-comparisons, graph-theory

I have two sets of weighted and directed graphs with the same nodes. I expect that between these two families there is a variation in connectivity driven by some phenomenon. How could I highlight this and possibly evaluate which links are most relevant in this change?

Comment: I think there are a number of similar questions whose answers may be at least partly relevant to yours, e.g. https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/149765/comparing-undirected-weighted-graphs and https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/487815/comparing-directed-unweighted-graphs-with-a-dissimilar-number-of-nodes